# Where is AAD users-default-permissions (UserSettings) in Azure API (Graph or REST)?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I can't find a way to bring the data of "Restrict member users default permissions" -> "Users can register application" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions) in Azure API Rest or Graph.

I use "Get-MsolCompanyInformation" from powershell. I wanted to do this without logging in with an azure interactive account, but using an account and application using .NETFramework

How get the values programmatically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only manage these settings under user settings in Azure AD portal or using Azure AD MSOL module `Get-MsolCompanyInformation` and no API way to control as of today.

If you use msol module (Get-MsolCompanyInformation) which leverage Azure AD connect provisioning endpoint https://provisioningapi.microsoftonline.com/provisioningwebservice.svc (SOAP request based) to retrieve UserSettings which can't be used out of box like Graph API way.

[image]